# Download PDF from server to client in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, pdf

I have this code that should download my `.pdf` file saved on the server to my client but when I click the button it does not execute anything and it does not send me any error, I don't know if it has to do with a problem with the http request

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Ruta del archivo que deseas descargar en el servidor
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Archivos/prueba.pdf");

        // Nombre del archivo que se mostrará al usuario
        string fileName = "prueba.pdf";

        // Prepara la respuesta HTTP para la descarga del archivo
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMensaje.Text = "ERROR:" + ex;
        lblMensaje.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

I tried to send the execution to a new tab but it didn't work, it doesn't even open the tab

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidelines on posting the code and provide code related to the problem. Currently question makes it quite clear that code you posted does not get executed at all - so it is unclear why you have included it in the post. Also there is some random base64  image text included in the question - make sure to clean/clarify that too.

Comment: Yes, because I have seen that this code works to download the files, and I want to know why it is not executed, I don't know if it has to do with the permissions of my application, because since the file does not exist it does send me the error, but when If it exists, it does not activate anything

Answer (score 0):

adjust your response to this :

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Archivos/prueba.pdf");

string fileName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

byte[] fileBytes = File.IO.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

response.Clear();
response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment;filename={fileName}");
response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
response.End();
```